# Physical Meetups for Dhamma Discussion and Meditation

Tags: discussion

I am wondering if the site users are interested in doing a physical meetup and meditation?

Each person can organise in their respective cities.

Comment: One interesting group in Colombo is: https://www.facebook.com/groups/1535533086722963/

Comment: I live in Nugegoda, Sri Lanka. May be we can try organising some thing with local chapters?

Comment: Out of curiosity. Are your adopted parents Buddhists? How did you come in contact with Buddhism and get interested. Can this be replicated towards others in Denmark? I think we best more this conversation to email. My email address is sirinath1978m@gmail.com

Comment: OK. You are at an advantage to organise meetups as all of you will be learning together. In SL every one has their opinions and also cluttered with different teachers and interpretations. Send you a test mail so your mail may not get into spam filters.

Comment: I have created the following group but still noting organised arround it as yet: https://www.facebook.com/groups/672339399555834/